# Reactive UI / Blazor: Why is a View that inherits from ReactiveInjectableComponentBase<T> rendered twice?

Tags: mvvm, blazor, viewmodel, reactiveui

When I inherit a View from `ReactiveInjectableComponentBase<T>` the body of the View will be "rendered" twice. I noticed this because a `@foreach` loop was executed twice on activation of the view. This effect happens no matter how simple the View and the ViewModel are.

---

Simple reproduction repo: https://github.com/Lukzy/ReactiveUI.ExecutedTwiceBug

Bug filed on ReactiveUI GitHub: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/3256

---

I used the following code to simulate the behavior.

**ViewWithoutInherits:** "View rendered" will be executed once.

```
@page "/whatever"

@using System.Diagnostics

@{
    Trace.TraceInformation("View renderer");
}
```

**ViewWithInherits:** "View rendered" will be executed twice.

```
@page "/whatever"

@using System.Diagnostics

@inherits ReactiveInjectableComponentBase<ViewModel>

@{
    Trace.TraceInformation("View renderer");
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
using ReactiveUI;

public class TestViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
}
```

Am I missing something or is this a bug? Any help or hint is highly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE #1:**

I replaced the trace code with the suggestion from Dylan Barquilla.

```
@code {

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("View renderer in FIRST RENDER");
        }

        Trace.TraceInformation("View renderer");

        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }
}
```

Output from **ViewWithoutInherits:**

```
View renderer in FIRST RENDER
View renderer
```

Output from **ViewWithInherits:**

```
View renderer in FIRST RENDER
View renderer
View renderer
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

**ViewWithInherits:** foreach-loop will be executed twice.

```
@page "/whatever"

@inherits ReactiveInjectableComponentBase<ViewModel>

@foreach (var value in ViewModel.Values)
{
    <p>@(value)</p>
}
```

**ViewWithInject:** foreach-loop will be executed once.

```
@page "/whatever"

@foreach (var value in ViewModel.Values)
{
    <p>@(value)</p>
}

@code {
    [Inject]
    public TestViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
using ReactiveUI;

public class TestViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public List<string> Values{ get; set; } = new()
    {
        "a",
        "b"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 2: after cloning the repo, to prove what I want to say.

I just added a button on both components, with a simple handler (with no real effect).

```
<button @onclick="@OnClickHandler">Click on me</button>
//-- CODE PART --
public string Test { get; set; } = string.Empty;

private void OnClickHandler()
{
    Test = "New";
}
```

You will see that every time you click on the button, the `Foreach loop was executed [N] times` will be updated with a two increments.

It is a perfect normal behavior in Blazor. A component being re render is a normal thing, and happen A LOT of time, basically every UI interaction can force the component to re render. So it should not cause you trouble, and Blazor [has some useful methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0) (`SetParametersAsync` or `OnInitialized`) that can be used to apply logic only **once**, not every time the component is rendering.

If a component is inherit of another component, it could be the parent to cause this re rendering, by apply some logic (adding fields, updating fields etc.).

---

EDIT: I just checked the new outputs that you get, and I think the explanation is that the library that you use update or inject something in the component, after its first rendering, for example adding some fields on it or anything. It is a classic behavior with some other Blazor libraries, so I guess it is pretty normal - but you can ask in the Github / forum of the library you use to be sure.

So it basically means that if you want your code do be executed only once, I suggest you to use the following:

```
@code {
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            // Do whatever you need here, it will be executed only once
        }
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender); // this line is important for Blazor lifecycle 
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question with the trace output.

Comment: Updated my answer according to that. If you need any other help do not hesitate :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution does not work in my case. I need to have a @foreach loop to populate HTML based on a collection. The code provided in the question is just the simplest way possible to reproduce the issue. The only library I’m currently using is ReactiveUI in the latest version.

Comment: So could you please insert the example? With the `@foreach(...)` statement? Cause usually  it should be based on a Field of your component, so not being "run twice"

Comment: I added a simplified example as UPDATE #2.

Comment: I also created a reproduction repo you can find here: https://github.com/Lukzy/ReactiveUI.ExecutedTwiceBug

Comment: Thanks @Letho, I just updated my answer to give you more explanation on how Blazor behaves.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the example.

I get your point but I still consider this an unwanted or at least unexpected behavior. As you have also written in your answer, this seems to be because of an implementation detail in the parent.